# Gwt: menu based application

Tags: gwt, layout, menu

I want a webapp skeleton similar to GWT "Showcase" example.

I mean: an entrypoint "docklayoutpanel", with a 'west' area (the menu) and a 'center' (the app sections).

How can I make the anchors/buttons in the menu uibinder "open" the variuos webapp sections in the center zone?

Do I have to pass it a reference to the "ContentWrapper" (the 'center' uibinder)?  Or is there a less coupling way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there a less coupling way?

Yes, there is. You can make use of GWT's history support (documented at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html)

So you can either create a new history token on button click, or use the [Hyperlink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) widget for your "buttons".

Then you need to register a ValueChangeHandler using `History.addValueChangeHandler()`, and you can switch the content of your center widget in that handler - nicely decoupled from your button code.